# How can I read all the files with a similar pattern in a folder and pass them as a comma separated string to Python?

Tags: bash, echo

I have this bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

some_code.py -i 1_xxx.txt,2_xxx.txt,...,10_xxx.txt  -o something.txt
```

The list `"1_xxx.txt,2_xxx.txt,...,10_xxx.txt"` contains the names of the files in the folder that have `xxx` in common.

The input to `some_code.py` must come after `-i` in the form of the file names separated by comma with no spacing.

My question is: how can I echo the filenames (with `xxx`) into a comma separated string and pass it to my Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use command substitution and set `IFS` to `,`. Assume you have

```
$ ls
1098_xxx.txt  20260_xxx.txt  22286_xxx.txt  32025_xxx.txt  6433_xxx.txt
```

then you can do<sup>1</sup>

```
echo "$(IFS=,; f=(*xxx*); printf '%s\n' "${f[*]}")"
```

resulting in

```
1098_xxx.txt,20260_xxx.txt,22286_xxx.txt,32025_xxx.txt,6433_xxx.txt
```

or, for your use case:

```
some_code.py -i "$(IFS=,; f=(*xxx*); printf '%s\n' "${f[*]}")" -o something.txt
```

`$(...)` is command substitution, and `${f[*]}` is a parameter expansion that uses the first character from `IFS` as the element separator.

This should be save for file names containing any character, including spaces and glob characters; if you have hidden files (starting with `.`), they'll be ignored, unless you set the `shopt -s dotglob` shell option.

Also, if you potentially have no files matching `*xxx*`, you could set `shopt -s nullglob` to prevent creating a file that's literally called `*xxx*`.

---

<sup>1</sup> `echo "$(cmd)"` is usually an anti-pattern to be replaced by just `cmd`; I'm using it here with `echo` as a placeholder for other commands. Using command substitution also has the benefit of changing `IFS` only there and not in the parent shell.

Comment: Thanks. It does exactly what I need.

Comment: @Amessihel Good point, actually - that could be messed up when filenames start with `-`. Should use `printf`!

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on the exact format, you can do it with with bash loops:

```
f=(*_xxx.txt); for w in ${f[@]}; do echo -n "$w,"; done
```

This will generate string:

```
1_xxx.txt,2_xxx.txt,...,10_xxx.txt,
```

Now if you want to remove the last `,` use `sed s'/.$//'`, pipe it like this:

```
f=(*_xxx.txt); for w in ${f[@]}; do echo -n "$w,"; done | sed s'/.$//'
```

This will generate the string that you're after. You can then wrap a `()` around it for use within your bash command.